# EDMX adding 1 to some field names

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio, edmx

Using Visual studio 2013 we are using the edmx feature to build the model based on the database.

Unfortunately when we update the model from the database some of the fields seem to have the number 1 added to their name.
For example the table in the database looks like this
[image: Database view]

But the model in visual studio is being created like this

[image: Model view]

How can I stop it adding the number 1 after the field name? This is happening in more than one table too.
I have tried regenerating the table on its own or the entire database and its not making any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I think I have found out what the reason is.
If any of the tables in my database have the same name as the field name is where this issue is happening.

If you change the field name in the database then it should be fine. e.g the the example above change the field name from ClientTitle to ClientTitleName.